# How to place a Button in the center of a row?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to place a Button in the center of a row of a Container , the Button is the only component of the Container. How to achieve that ?

Comment: code please... we cant read minds.. maybe use `style="margin:auto;"`

Comment: Container c = new Container(); Button b = new Button(); c.addComponent(b);

Comment: @Andy: Are you using multiple button's?

Comment: @bhakki: just one LWUIT Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Container c = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER)); 
Button b = new Button(); 
c.addComponent(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `BorderLayout` to `Container`. Then add the `Button` into `Container` and set the constraints to `CENTER`.

For example,

```
Container c = new Container(new BorderLayout());
Button btn = new Button("Sample");
c.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, btn);
```